Interviews for a manager Earth Observation position
Why the company called me for an interview, I did not have required qualifications. The company was looking for Manager - Earth Observation with a masters degree minimum. I have a bachelor's degree in geospatial engineering honors, but they end up calling me for the interview??? Are there any chance of being considered for the post????

You can check the internet to see if this is a legitimate company. For example, google "Is company XYZ legitimate ?". Look up the company's linkedIn profile to see how long they have been in the business ? What are the LinkedIn profiles of current employees ? Do the employees look like real and professional workers ?

Do you have any experience as a manager ? If not, then that company is a scam for sure.

Could be real, could be a scam. Do your homework and research the company and the position. Asking strangers on the internet will not help here.

"Manager" doesn't mean anything. Regardless, millions of new graduates are hired for "manager" repositions every year.

If the company "cold called" you rather than your contacting them, and is offering you a higher powered job than you would normally be looking for, be very careful; that could be a recruiter trying a bait-and-switch to get you into their files, or it could be an outright scam. I've seen both

Yes.  Qualifications in a job posting are just a wishlist.  Apply anyway if you think you can make a case for doing the job, and sometimes - as in this case apparently - you will get a shot.
As an aside, one of the factors behind job and pay disparity is that more privileged groups are more willing to apply for “stretch” fits like this and get them. Get in there and explain why you can do it.
